# Is there a function to add a buffer of (NaN) values around a NumPy ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, raster, numpy-ndarray

I am working with a thematic raster of land use classes. The goal is to split the raster into smaller tiles of a given size. For example, I have a raster of 1490 pixels and I want to split it into tiles of 250x250 pixels. To get tiles of equal size, I would want to increase the width of the raster to 1500 pixels to fit in exactly 6 tiles. To do so, I need to increase the size of the raster by 10 pixels.

I am currently opening the raster with the `rasterio` library, which returns a NumPy ndarray. Is there a function to add a buffer around this array? The goal would be something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1,4,5],
    [4,5,5],
    [1,2,2]
])

a_with_buffer = a.buffer(a, 1) # 2nd argument refers to the buffer size
```

Then `a_with_buffer` would look as following:

```
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,1,4,5,0],
[0,4,5,5,0],
[0,1,2,2,0],
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```py
>>> np.pad(a, 1)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 4, 5, 5, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Would it be possible to set the padding width and height at different values? I could not find it in the docs.

Comment: @Sytze Sure, it's possible to provide one 2-tuple per dimension, specifying left and right padding: `[(l1, r1), (l2, r2)]`. It's mentioned in the docs at parameter `pad_width`.

Answer (score 1):

you can create `np.zeros` then insert `a` in the index what you want like below.

Try this:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,4,5],[4,5,5],[1,2,2]])

>>> b = np.zeros((5,5))

>>> b[1:1+a.shape[0],1:1+a.shape[1]] = a

>>> b
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 4., 5., 0.],
       [0., 4., 5., 5., 0.],
       [0., 1., 2., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```